# Python Beautiful Soup - Yahoo Finance Data, Annual vs Quarterly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a quick question about parsing through the yahoo finance page using beautiful soup.

Here is an example of the page I would like to extract data from.

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/cash-flow?p=AAPL

I am successfully able to extract data from the using BeautifulSoup but I cannot figure out how to toggle between annual vs quarterly data. Therefore, I am only able to extract annual data. It seems the url doesn't change when switching to quarterly. From browser inspection, it seems to toggle a table which I am not sure how to handle using beautiful soup.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions? 
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like javascript changes data source, you will have to extract data from json but looking at the amount of jsons in the source code it won't be easy.

Comment: I was thinking I would have to actually click on the quarterly button using selenium (maybe?) and then I guess parse the table after? I don’t have any experience with selenium so not sure if this is possible.

Comment: That would be much easier. I was digging a bit in the jsons but gave up eventually, some jsons are too huge to comprehend.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you so much for giving it a shot! I will update you on my progress here!

Answer (score 1):

You can  isolate the json on the page and get all the yearly and quarterly cash flow statements.

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

soup_script = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("root.App.main")).text
json_script = json.loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})",soup_script)[1])
fin_data = json_script['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']

cash_yr = fin_data['cashflowStatementHistory']['cashflowStatements']
cash_qtrs = fin_data['cashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly']['cashflowStatements']
```

The balance sheet (balanceSheetHistory, balanceSheetHistoryQuarterly) and income statements (incomeStatementHistory, incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly) are there as well.

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `>>> json_script = json.loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})",soup_script)[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: how would you make this data loadable to a pandas dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

@user
Try this:

```
json.loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})",soup_script).group(1))
```

@Aran Freel
Try this:

```
cf_annual = {}
for yr in range(len(cash_yr)):
    cf_annual[yr] = pd.DataFrame(cash_yr[yr]).T

cf_annual
```